# Getting the list of unanswered quizz by a player

Tags: parse-platform

I am working on a small quizz application to learn Parse.

In terms of data I have a table Quiz, a table Player and a table QuizAnswered. The table QuizAnswered contains a list of Quiz where a Player has taken part. So it is a many to many relationship.

I would like to get the list of Quiz that a player has NOT taken part in.

I have been able to get it but I need to do two api calls and I wondering if there is any better way to do it. Here is the code I am using I am not very proud of it to be frank.

```
public void getUnansweredQuizListForPlayer(Player p) {
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> quizAnsweredQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("QuizAnswered");
    quizAnsweredQuery.whereEqualTo("player", p);
    quizAnsweredQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(final List<ParseObject> quizAnsweredList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                ParseQuery<Quiz> quizQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Quiz");
                quizQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Quiz>() {
                    public void done(List<Quiz> quizList, ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            ArrayList<Quiz> quizzes = new ArrayList<Quiz>();
                            for (Quiz quiz : quizList) {
                                boolean answered  = false;
                                for (ParseObject o :quizAnsweredList) {
                                   Quiz quizAnswered = (Quiz) o.getParseObject("quiz");
                                    if (quizAnswered.getObjectId().equals(quiz.getObjectId())) {
                                        answered = true;
                                    }
                                }
                                if (!answered) {
                                    quizzes.add(quiz);
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Is there a way to get the list of not participated quiz for a player in only one Query ?

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store `objectId` of `Quiz` in `Player`'s `answeredQuizList` column, which will be array containing `objectId`'s of quizes which the user gave answer to.

And then make `Quiz` query with: (pseudo-code)

```
query whereKey:"objectId" notContainedIn: user.answeredQuizList
```

Comment: Thank for the answer, I guess I will duplicate the answeredQuizList. As I need to store the score for each quiz for each player I can not get rid of QuizAnswered table. But I think it is fine to have duplicate data if it is easier to query it in the noSQL space.